# $\Omega_X$ locally free $\implies$ $X$ smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be $n$-dimensional scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field. In the proof of Proposition 7.4.11 in [Gathmann](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/chapter-7.pdf), the first paragraph reads

> If $\Omega_X$ is locally free of rank $n$ then its fibers at any point $P$, i.e. the cotangent spaces $T_{X,P}^\vee$, have dimension $n$.

Here $\Omega_X$ is the sheaf of relative differentials on $X$ (relative to $\operatorname{Spec} k$).

I don't see why this is true. My understanding is that (a) the cotangent space $T^\vee_{X,p}$ is the Zariski cotangent space of $\mathscr O_{X,p}$ (i.e. $\mathfrak m/ \mathfrak m^2$) and (b) the fiber of a locally free sheaf $\mathscr F$ at the point $P$ is given by $i^\ast \mathscr F$, where $i : P \hookrightarrow X$ is inclusion. I can't see why these are isomorphic.

Comment: I'm not sure of your definition of cotangent space: $\Omega_X$ is the cotangent sheaf and its stalk at a point $p$ is the cotangent space at that point. This is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{m}_p / \mathfrak{m}_p^2$ when $X$ is smooth at $p$ (which is essentially what you're trying to show), where $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, but this is certainly not $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$.

Comment: Thanks, you're right -- I had inadvertently misread the definition of the cotangent space from a different source. I've fixed the question accordingly. Would super appreciate it if you could fill in the part at the end about why this is "essentially what you're trying to show". Thanks.

Comment: How did you define $\Omega$?

Comment: Formally, Gathmann (linked above, Def 7.4.6) defines it via the diagonal morphism $\Delta : X \to X \times_Y X$, where $Y = \operatorname{Spec} k$.

Comment: Do you have access to Hartshorne? I think II.8.7 is what you're asking. The heart of the matter is showing that maps out of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ correspond to derivations.

Comment: I'll see if I can find myself a copy -- thanks for the tip.